# Aratanaru and atarashii usage

Tags: usage

As far as I understand aratanaru and atarashii roughly translate to "new" . When each one have to be used or what are the differences?

Comment: Did you mean to write "atarashii" perhaps? From what I've just read on Yahoo Answers, "aratashii" is an old reading that didn't really survive due to frequent misreadings or something like that.

Comment: yes, I meant atarashii, sorry, editing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use 新たな and 新しい](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4769/542) but not exactly since this one asks about aratanaru while the other asks about aratana.

Comment: 新たなる cannot be used at the end of sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atarashii（新しい）, Aratana（新たな）and Aratanaru（新たなる）are all translated to "new".
But, 新たなる is an exaggerated version of 新たな.
In general, you don't use 新たなる in daily conversations.

It could be appeared in below contexts;

> Last night's his live performance marked a new chapter in the history of Hip Hop. 新たなる1ページを刻んだ。
>
> As a company slogan, "新たなる挑戦" as in a new challenge