# What is the difference between 新規 with 新しい and 新た?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, wago-and-kango

I know **新しい{あたらしい}** and **新た{あらた}** and I understood that the latter is usually used in newspaper because it brings more politeness/formality.

However, I encountered **新規{しんき}** in a newspaper [article](https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPBY71P9PBXUHBI007.html):

> 新型コロナウイルスの感染が広がるロシアで、1日の**新規**感染者数や死者数が連日、記録更新を続けている。

According to Jisho [dictionary](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%96%B0%E8%A6%8F), **新規{しんき}** means new/fresh as well. It makes me wonder, what are the nuances between this word and **新しい{あたらしい}** and **新た{あらた}** ? Is it mostly a prefix word like 新 kanji (e.g. 新年, 新学期...) ?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up 新規 and 規則. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4769/5010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

新規 and 新たな cannot be used as a predicate, and they cannot be used in comparative sentences, either.

| pre-noun adjectival | adverbial | comparison | predicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 新しい計画 | 新しく計画する | これより新しい計画 | この計画は新しい |
| 新たな計画 | 新たに計画する | ❌これより新たな計画 | ❌この計画は新ただ |
| 新規(の)計画 | 新規に計画する | ❌これより新規な計画 | ❌この計画は新規だ |

新しい is a plain word, 新た is a bookish and a little dramatic word (∼ "brand-new"), and 新規 is a technical-sounding word. 新規 is not a word we commonly see in lyrics. 新たな夢 sounds more dramatic than 新しい夢, but 新規の夢 sounds simply odd.

As 新規 is a kango (Sino-Japanese word with on-readings), it's often used before another kango.

I may be wrong, but 新規 may tend to mean "first-time" rather than "new". 新規客 and 新しい客 can both refer to "first-time customer (who has never visited the store before)" and "new customer (e.g., 8th visitor of the day after the first 7)", but I feel 新規客 tends to refer to the former. There is even an expression [ご新規さん](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%94%E6%96%B0%E8%A6%8F). The same can be said for 新規感染 vs 新たな感染; both can refer to first-time infection and reinfection, but 新規感染 tends to refer to the former.

Comment: Just my two yen but 新規 sounds to me best in the collocation "newly created" or "newly produced".